# Show/hide divs using IDs and hashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, show

I'm looking to create a simple show/hide div set up using IDs and hash values. If you click the link, which has a hash value, it shows the div with the same ID as the hash. I know there's a few tools out there, but I'd prefer to do this using jQuery/JS if possible.

One thing to note is that all the hashes, and IDs are pulled in dynamically from the CMS based on the page title, then sanitises it — so I can't hard-code any IDs or hashes in the jQuery.

Here's my set up:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#aquatic-health">Aquatic Health</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#environment">Environment</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="aquatic-health">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.</p>
</div>
<div id="environment">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.</p>
</div>
```

Many many thanks in advance,
R

Comment: Have you tried anything? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Y dont u refer the anchor tag with an id
so that on click of u can show the hidden div...

Comment: Show your js code of what you have tried on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (if you can add a class to each content div when they are generated) :

EDIT => display the first div by default

http://jsfiddle.net/eNTtN/3/

HTML :

```
<div class="menu">


<ul>
    <li><a href="#aquatic-health">Aquatic Health</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#environment">Environment</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="aquatic-health">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vide elaboraret persequeris at, clita vitae eirmod in eos, eros nostrud apeirian ea per.</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="environment">
  <p>Blabla</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu li a").click(function(){
        $(".hidden").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
    /* Show the first div by default */
    $(".hidden:first").show();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

```
$('.menu a').on('click', function(){
    $( $(this).attr('href') ).toggle(); // prop() can be used
});
```

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/FsCHV/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't quite work, however. It needs to only show one div at a time and preferably the divs set to display:none with the first div (:first) shown my default.

Comment: You added display:none inline — is there any other way to do this (ie. showing the first div)

Comment: on document load, you can hide all the divs, and show only the first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(.menu li a).click(function(){
var hrefValue = $(this).attr("href");
$(hrefValue).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu').find('a').on('click', function(){
    var dest = $(this).attr('href');
    $(dest).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.menu a').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $(id).css('display', 'block');
    });

});
```

Or you can use a toggle

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.menu a').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            $(id).toggle();
        });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FZTmH/

You can make yourself a close button.